# Change name of doc using google scripts file export

Tags: google-apps-script

I am sending a google doc as an attachment in an email which is working fine however the attachment is called 'export.docx' and I can't figure out how to change it. I am using this API - https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/export

My code is below. If someone could help me to change the name of the attached file that would be great! Thanks!

```
function run(id, callback) {
  var service = getDriveService();
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    var token = service.getAccessToken();
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/' + id + '/export?mimeType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
      }
    });
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: email,
      subject: "Attachments",
      htmlBody: "Please see attached.",
      attachments: [response]
    });
  } else {
    Logger.log("Access denied")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this to rename the name like so:

```
function run(id, callback) {
  var service = getDriveService();
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    var token = service.getAccessToken();
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/' + id + '/export?mimeType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
      }
    });
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: email,
      subject: "Attachments",
      htmlBody: "Please see attached.",
      attachments: [response.getBlob().setName("NewName")]  
    });
  } else {
    Logger.log("Access denied")
  }
}
```

Basically, convert the response to a blob and a setnewName to use, using setName function

Hope that helps